# How to save or update multiple tables at once in c++ in the sqlite database?

Tags: c++, sqlite

```
       QSqlQuery qry4;
       QSqlQuery qry5;
       QSqlQuery qry6;



 qry3.prepare("INSERT INTO apra(Source,Medium,Subject,'Date & Time received document','Date & Time RRO forwarded to HOO','ControlNo.') values('"+src+"','"+med+"','"+key+"','"+one+"','"+one+"','"+res+"')");
       qry4.prepare("INSERT INTO bag(Source,Medium,Subject,'Date & Time received document','Date & Time RRO forwarded to HOO','ControlNo.') values('"+src+"','"+med+"','"+key+"','"+one+"','"+one+"','"+res+"')");
       qry5.prepare("INSERT INTO ben(Source,Medium,Subject,'Date & Time received document','Date & Time RRO forwarded to HOO','ControlNo.') values('"+src+"','"+med+"','"+key+"','"+one+"','"+one+"','"+res+"')");
       qry6.prepare("INSERT INTO cent(Source,Medium,Subject,'Date & Time received document','Date & Time RRO forwarded to HOO','ControlNo.') values('"+src+"','"+med+"','"+key+"','"+one+"','"+one+"','"+res+"')");


 if(qry3.exec()){
           QMessageBox::information(this,"Database","qry3");
       }else{
           QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("error::"),qry3.lastError().text());
       }
       if(qry4.exec()){
           QMessageBox::information(this,"Database","qry4");
       }else{
           QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("error::"),qry4.lastError().text());
       }
       if(qry5.exec()){
           QMessageBox::information(this,"Database","qry5");
       }else{
           QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("error::"),qry5.lastError().text());
       }
       if(qry6.exec()){
           QMessageBox::information(this,"Database","qry6");
       }else{
           QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("error::"),qry6.lastError().text());
       }
```

I want to know a simpler way to update tables in sqlite. Because this method pops the information prompt 3 times also and what if i have 10 query and more it will be time consuming and not ideal.

Comment: If all 4 of your tables have the same columns should they be separate tables or just 1 table with an extra column containing an enum?

Comment: Also read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection and use prepared statement placeholders

Comment: @AlanBirtles they are all separated sir.

Comment: Yes but what I'm saying is if they weren't separated you wouldn't have a problem

Comment: @AlanBirtles ohh i see, is there any solution then for my problem? sorry i'm just starting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you created all queries with placeholders and that they all have the same parameters in the same order:

```
qry3.prepare("INSERT INTO apra(Source,Medium,Subject,'Date & Time received document','Date & Time RRO forwarded to HOO','ControlNo.') values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
qry4.prepare("INSERT INTO bag(Source,Medium,Subject,'Date & Time received document','Date & Time RRO forwarded to HOO','ControlNo.') values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
qry5.prepare("INSERT INTO ben(Source,Medium,Subject,'Date & Time received document','Date & Time RRO forwarded to HOO','ControlNo.') values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
qry6.prepare("INSERT INTO cent(Source,Medium,Subject,'Date & Time received document','Date & Time RRO forwarded to HOO','ControlNo.') values(?,?,?,?,?,?)");
```

You can loop over them as follows:

```
bool success = true;
for (auto& q_wrapper : std::initializer_list<std::reference_wrapper<QSqlQuery>>{qry3, qry4, qry5, qry6}) {
  QSqlQuery& q = q_wrapper.get();
  q.addBindValue(src);
  q.addBindValue(med);
  q.addBindValue(key);
  q.addBindValue(one);
  q.addBindValue(one);
  q.addBindValue(res);
  success &&= q.exec();
  if (!success) {
    QMessageBox::critical(this,tr("error::"),q.lastError().text())
    break;
  }
}

if (success) {
  QMessageBox::information(this,"Database","all queries succeeded");
}
```

Possible improvements:

- Switch to [:named placeholders](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qsqlquery.html#approaches-to-binding-values) and store all your placeholders in a `QMap<QString, QVariant>`.
- Wrap everything in a transaction. This enables you to avoid partial updates. (Use `QSqlDatabase().transaction()` to start a transaction and either call `QSqlDatabase().commit()` (if success) or `QSqlDatabase().rollback()` (if !success)

Comment: I am receiving this error in the code: 

: error: no member named 'addBindValue' in 'std::reference_wrapper<QSqlQuery>'

should i make a public thread? if yes how can i do it?

Comment: Sorry, that was a last-minute change. You need to call `.get()` on the reference_wrapper. Updated my answer.